# Why is the div wider than its content?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-flex-layout

I'm trying to create a page with a 20-60-20 flex fill layout but the div in the center which should make up 60% of the page is wider than its content so it makes its content look like it is off-center.

[image]

home.component.html:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap"  fxLayoutGap="20px grid">
  <div *ngFor="let data of DUMMY_DATA">
    <mat-card class="example-card" >
      <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
      <mat-card-content class="description-max-height">
        <p>
          {{data.description.length > 100 ? data.description.substring(0, 100) + '...' : data.description}}
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

home.component.css:

```
.example-card {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
}

.description-max-height {
  max-height: 30px;
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Some title</span>
    <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
    <button mat-button color="accent" (click)="openLoginDialog()">Log In</button>
    <button mat-button color="accent" (click)="openSignupDialog()">Register</button>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div fxFlex="20"></div>
  <router-outlet fxFlex="60"></router-outlet>
  <div fxFlex="20"></div>
</div>
```

app.compoenent.css:

```
.toolbar-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

How can I implement this so that  will display the home.component.html on the center of the page without it being wider than it's contet?

You can find a Stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6dhaww)

Comment: Can u create stackblitz example?

Comment: @pc_coder I added a Stackblitz example

Comment: I haven't seen any problem it is 60% your next image doesn't fit so go down then u see this empyt area? What do u want as result?

Answer (score 1):

The `router-outlet` isn't a container. All the content routed to a `router-outlet` is rendered as a sibling node, not as an outlet's child node. So you should wrap the `router-outlet` with a 60%-width `div`.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma616960106433166)

```html
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div fxFlex="20"></div>
  <div fxFlex="60">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="20"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding `fxLayoutAlign="centre"` to the `fxLayout` div(top level div) in `home-component.html` should align the items/cards in centre in the container.

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap"  fxLayoutGap="20px grid" fxLayoutAlign="center">
```